# Ubuntu Software is not opening

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I need to install pgAdminIII from ubuntu software-center but the software-center doesn't open this morning. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Well. Try pasting this in terminal and tell us the output

'software-center'

Comment: Try a reboot [16.04 Software Centre not opening](//askubuntu.com/q/761086)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall the software center

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

or if you're running Gnome

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/gnome-software
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install  --reinstall gnome-software packagekit
```

If it's still now working then type

```
gnome-software
```

Or

```
software-center
```

And update your question with output

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: Okay, let me try this

Comment: this doesn't also work

Comment: Oh! Something is responding :-D

Comment: is it working now? because you've not posted the output yet

Comment: @PatrickTSHABA you can "accept the answer as useful" or "upvote the answer" so that other users know that it's solved, just a suggestion